# Watch App - Replace ... when text is too long

Tags: swift, watchkit, watchos-2, picker

I have a problem with the size of my text.
When my text is too long in a WKInterfaceLabel, no problem, I just add line or I pass line at 0 to increase automatically the number of lines.

But with **WKInterfacePicker**, impossible to increase the number of line and I have "..." at the end of my text.

**Do you have solutions to display all my text or, at least, to delete this "..." and replace it by some letters more from my text.** I work with Swift.

For the second solution, I prefer have "My text" than "My te..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, this is not possible. Apple doesn't provide any sort of way on managing that.

A possible, but rather complicated solution would be making a costume picker with labels with multiple lines and using the newly implemented [WKCrownSequencer](https://developer.apple.com/reference/watchkit/wkcrownsequencer) as well as the [WKCrownDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/reference/watchkit/wkcrowndelegate) in watchOS 3 to detect the state of the digital crown. The default picker animations might be impossible or very difficult to reproduce, but it might fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

try this set in size width = size to fit width content